# Need to be able to get data from two Solr collections

Tags: solr

I have two Solr collections:

Collection A - is a unique record set (several hundred million)
Collection B - is a detail set that contains details regarding the first set (4 billion records)

**Example:
Collection A**

Basket ID, Cost, Header

1, 5650, 1

2, 6500, 1

**Collection B**

ID, Basket ID, Description, Cost

1,1,Apple,2000

2,1,Pear,2000

3,1,Orange,1650

4,2,Apple,3000

5,2,Orange,2000

6,2,Book,1500

I want to create the average cost by description, the formula we want is SUM(b.cost)/COUNT(DISTINCT basket_id), for example Apple would be 2500

Today, I have API calls hitting collection b to get the sum of cost by descriptions and then divide using the UNIQUE(basket id) function but this is not 100% accurate and only an approximation, this causes clear data issues on our web interface. We have billions of records in collection b.

What I need is either a 100% accurate UNIQUE count of basket IDs or to join to a and get SUM(header) from A.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at Streaming Expressions? They're made for analytics and queries like this: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/streaming-expressions.html - you also have the analytics component, but I'm not sure you can make that work with multiple collections: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/analytics.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a relational database. This is a relational DB problem with joins and unique results. Solr is not going to be fast for this.